# railsのMechanizeでのスクレイピングについて

Tags: web-scraping, mechanize

```
<table class ="profile">
<tr>
    <td class="title">ほげ１</td>
    <td class="content"ほげ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title">ほげ２</td>
    <td class="content">ほげ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="title">ほげ３</td>
    <td class="content">ほげ</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

上記のようなtext情報をcontentごとのtext情報を一つずつスクレイピングしたいのですが、class名が統一されているためまとまったtext情報が取得されてしまいます。contentごとにDBに保存させたいのですがなにかいい方法はありますでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get( 'http://localhost:8000/test.html' )
page.search( 'table.profile tr' ).each do |tr|
  p tr.at( 'td.title' ).inner_html
  p tr.at( 'td.content' ).inner_html
end
```

こんな感じで個々を取得できると思いますが、どうでしょう？